# Querying speeds

Tags: sql, hiveql

In a large database, is it faster to perform a query such as

```
select * from table where a = 1 and b = 2 or b = 3 or b = 4;
```

or

```
select * from table where a = 1 and b = 2;
select * from table where a = 1 and b = 3;
select * from table where a = 1 and b = 4;
```

Comment: i think it depend on if `a` is key or index or not...

Comment: Just a picky note, the first query is going to return a lot more than you think it will because of missing parenthesis around the collection of variable b.  `select * from table where a = 1 and (b = 2 or b = 3 or b = 4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the queries are not equivalent. I assume the first query should read:

```
select * from table where a = 1 and (b = 2 or b = 3 or b = 4);
```

For clarity I would suggest:

```
select * from table where a = 1 and b in (2, 3, 4);
```

In general this will perform better than asking three different queries as in the second alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You should rely on the DBMS to do the optimisation for you. If the second were quicker, then the DBMS would do it that way anyway.

Go with the first (but put parentheses round the `b` conditions, as Tommy suggests).